# How do i pull a private image from dockerhub with 2FA enabled?

Tags: kubernetes, dockerhub

I have one of my images private and was getting access with the imagePullSecrets: up until now but after enabling 2FA for docker-hub Kubernetes can no longer pull my image, how do I solve this?

currently using:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

Comment: I know that the Access Tokens exists but is there a free alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new imagePullSecret and use it in your manifests.

Login with your username and personal access token. this will update your ~/.docker/config.json

```
docker login registry.example.com -u <your_username> -p <your_personal_access_token>
```

Create your imagePullSecret using the updated config.json

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Update your deployment,statefulset,pod,jobs to use this new secret

Alternatively, if you want to make this imagePullSecret default for a namespace. Just make sure that the secret exists in that namespace. Secret may have same name in multiple namespaces as it is a namespaced object.

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "regcred"}]}'
```